# How can I adapt this circuit to use a slide switch as opposed to a momentary push button switch?

Tags: arduino, mosfet, switches

I need to be able to switch off my product for long term storage. I also need it to shut off automatically on low power. The device software needs to do housekeeping before shutting down. I found a tutorial online that uses a load switch circuit to accomplish half of the task. The problem with this circuit is it only shuts off in code.

[image]

How can I adapt this circuit to use a slide switch as opposed to a momentary push button switch?

Thanks for your time.
Tim Cerka

Comment: put the slide switch in series with the power supply

Comment: Something I should have mentioned in the post. The device software needs to do housekeeping before shutting down. I believe that means I can't simply run the switch in series with the power supply.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the switch with a 1-10uF capacitor and add the slide switch in series with the power supply.

The capacitor has to effect to momentarily pull down the gate of the P mos, which allows it to switch the circuit on. Connect the "Off" side of the switch to GND to discharge the capacitor when it's off.

Comment: When changing the switch to off, would this just cut power, or could I do some housekeeping before cutting power?

Comment: yes it would just switch the power off

Comment: Wanted to confirm the size of that capacitor 1-10 µF. That's a big one. Can I send you an updated schematic to be sure I'm on the right track?

Comment: I'm also confused about where to put the switch. On side of the switch to VDC and Off side of the switch to GND

Comment: @TimCerka What are your size limitations, if 1 μF is too big? I'm pretty sure you can get 1 μF caps in 0201.

Comment: @Hearth No, I've got one all lined-up from Mouser. It's just the first time I've worked with one that big.

Comment: @TimCerka Capacitances from 10 pF all the way up to 10s of mF (usually marked as 10000s of μF) are pretty common to see in different applications! 0.1-10 μF might be the most commonly used range, though that's just a gut feeling from experience, not backed up by any data.

Comment: @TimCerka 1uF cap are very small, you probably have one with much higher voltage that you need. Check that the voltage rating is a bit higher than that of the battery when charging.